# I am getting list of facebook friends of my own fb account using me/likes but i switch account list didn't show

Tags: android

I am getting list of facebook friends of my own fb account using me/likes but i switch account list didn't show

> Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   400, errorCode: 100, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage:
>   Unsupported get request. Object with ID '883764371736932' does not
>   exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
>   support this operation.

Comment: you need to give a lot more detail before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the other account you are using has 'Turned off Platform'. Follow [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/211829542181913) to undo or  learn more info about.